# How to add custom class in wagtail richtextfiled

Tags: javascript, django, wagtail, hallo-js

how can i add button which adds class in hallo.js editor?

Here is my code, but it dont works, it ony register fuction in wagtai;s edit interface.
In the end I need to add any class to selection or current tag.
Mb I can see it in html in someway and add classes manually?

```
(function() {
    (function(jQuery) {
        return jQuery.widget('IKS.center', { 
            options: {
                editable: null,
                toolbar: null,
                uuid: '',
                buttonCssClass: 'center'
            },
            populateToolbar: function(toolbar) {
                var buttonElement, buttonset;

                buttonset = jQuery('<span class="' + this.widgetName + '"></span>');
                buttonElement = jQuery('<span></span>');
                buttonElement.hallobutton({
                    uuid: this.options.uuid,
                    editable: this.options.editable,
                    label: 'Center element',
                    command: 'addClass("center")',
                    icon: 'icon-horizontalrule',
                    cssClass: this.options.buttonCssClass
                });
                buttonset.append(buttonElement);


                buttonset.hallobuttonset();
                return toolbar.append(buttonset);
            }
        });
    })(jQuery);

}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Wagtail customisation docs](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.11.1/advanced_topics/customisation/page_editing_interface.html#extending-the-wysiwyg-editor-hallo-js), you need to call `registerHalloPlugin`. You'll also need to [configure the whitelist](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.11.1/reference/hooks.html#construct-whitelister-element-rules) to allow your `<span>` element - rich text fields intentionally *don't* allow inserting arbitrary HTML. (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38097833/1853523 for more detail.)

However, I would strongly encourage using [StreamField](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.11.1/topics/streamfield.html) for this, rather than extending the rich text editor. The whole purpose of Wagtail is to keep a separation between the information content of pages, and its presentation. A button to say "center this text" is purely presentation - that's a detail that belongs in template code, not in your article content. Instead, you should ask: what is the *purpose* of this text? Is it a block-quote, a testimonial, an advert? Create block types for *that*, and then think about how to style them in the template. You'll have much more control over the presentation that way.

(further reading: [Rich text fields and faster horses](https://torchbox.com/blog/rich-text-fields-and-faster-horses/))

Comment: I tried StreamFiled but didnt understand how can I make several images for example. Heading - image - some text - another heading - another image?

Comment: I see it's in loop avalaible! Super! You age genious!